# CSS how do I make <hr> not overlay a <div>

Tags: html, css

I am currently struggling to move a `<hr>` element behind my div element. I tried already positioning but it didnt helped. Its still visible through the white parts, probably because these are transparent.

Maybe my idea how to achieve this is wrong. Here is a working example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbex4nnc/)

I want to create this menu:
[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
.intro-text h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ffa600;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.intro-text hr#myh {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffa600;
}
.intro-text div#myimgdiv {
    margin-top: -20.5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.intro-text span {
    margin: 0 1.5vw;
}
.intro-text img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
}

.make-border {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ffa909, 0 0 0 2px #ffffff;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 intro-text">
    <h1>Zimmer einstellen</h1>
    <hr id="myh"> 

    <div id="myimgdiv">
        <span id="step1">
            <img class="make-border" src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png">
        </span>
        <span id="step2">
            <img src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png"> 
        </span>
        <span id="step3">
            <img src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png">
        </span>
        <span id="step4">
            <img src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png">
        </span>
        <span id="step5">
            <img src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give background colors to your elements (radial-gradient for img or color for div)

you can also update borders and or colors to draw the hr https://jsfiddle.net/tbex4nnc/5/

```css
.intro-text h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffa600;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.intro-text hr#myh {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  color: #ffa600;
}

.intro-text div#myimgdiv {
  margin-top: -20.5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.intro-text span {
  margin: 0 1.5vw;
}

.intro-text img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
}

.make-border {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ffa909;
  background: white;
}

img {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, white 10px, transparent 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 intro-text">

  <h1>
    Zimmer einstellen
  </h1>

  <hr id="myh">

  <div id="myimgdiv"> <span id="step1"> <img class="make-border" src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png">
</span> <span id="step2"> <img src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png"> </span> <span id="step3"> <img src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png"> </span> <span id="step4"> <img src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png"> </span> <span id="step5"> <img src="http://imgur.com/oq54SFb.png"> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To your make-border class, add

```
background-color: #f0f0f0;
```

(or whatever is the same color as your page background)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make the background color of both images match your light gray page background. I would make each of the numbered images be like this image, with the background gray: [http://imgur.com/a/K2DbD](https://imgur.com/a/K2DbD). Then add this line of css:

```
.make-border {
background-color: #f3f5f6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
 .intro-text hr#myh {
     margin: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #ffa600;
 }
```

to

```
.intro-text hr#myh {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffa909; // changed from background-color to border-top
}
```

and added background to

```
.make-border {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ffa909, 0 0 0 0px #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```